# PHP implementation of Google Analytics

Tags: php, rest, google-analytics, server

I'm doing a server implementation of google analytics and have run into a problem. 
Events are not being saved and displayed on the analytics page.

I'm using 
https://github.com/theiconic/php-ga-measurement-protocol library.

```
 $analytics = new Analytics(true);
 $analytics
     ->setEventCategory($eventCategory)
     ->setEventAction($eventAction)
     ->setProtocolVersion('1')
     ->setTrackingId($trackingId)
     ->setClientId($clientId)
     ->setEventLabel($eventLabel)
     ->setEventValue('5');
```

The category, action, label and value match those from the preconfigured event on the analytics page. As a tracking ID I set `UA-110xxxxxx-x` 
and the client ID is `6415xxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxcl4mcokk813.apps.googleusercontent.com`

Function

```
$analytics->sendEvent();
```

Results in 200 server response... What am I missing?

Cheers!

Comment: Results in 200 server response means all is well.

Comment: Well it would be if the event would be registered in the analytics... i think

Comment: Response from the google side is always 200 even if there is an error actually... :)

Comment: have you checked the real time reports?  is it showing up there?

Comment: nope, unfortunately it's not there, I don't see an event but I see that there's been a movement on the site

Comment: Aye! It works I had to add ->setItemName('google analytics name here')